# RC Parallel Circuits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

---

A capacitor 27 and $\mu$F is connected to a battery
 of 21 V through a resistance of 14 M$\Omega$.

1) What 's the charge on his  parallel-plate?

2) To reduce such a charge of 16%, I connect a wire in parallel with the
condenser. 
What will be now the ddp across the parallel-plate capacitor?

3) What resistance the new wire must present to ensure this outcome?

Solutions: q = 576$\mu$C;   $V_c$ = 17.64 V;   $R_2$ = 2.666667K$\Omega$

---

I succeeded to find the solution for the question 1) and 2) but not the 3).

Here is what I tried:

the picture should be like this:

[image]

$R_1$ = 14 M$\Omega$

$V_f$ = 21 V

c = 27 $\mu$F

---

q = c * $V_f$ = 576 $\mu$ C

$V_c$ = $\frac{q}{c}$* (1 - 16/100) = 17.64 V

$R_2$ resistance in parallel to the capacitor

(1) $R_2$ * I = $V_c$

(2) $V_f$ = ( $R_2$ + $R_1$ ) * I

I tried to solve (1) and (2) to find the $R_2$ but the result I found is different from the solution.

Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by a $16$% drop in charge you mean $Q'=Q\times0.84$, that result ($R_2=2.66\,k\Omega $) is certainly wrong, as is deduced from your equations. The correct answer will be $R_2=73.5\, M\Omega$.

Also, intuitively if $R_2=2.66 \,k\Omega$ almost all of the source voltage will be over $R_1$ resistor, because $R_1=14000k\Omega>>R_2=2.66\,k\Omega$, and the charge of the capacitor will be dropped substantially (not by 16 percents):

$$R_2=2.66\,k\Omega\rightarrow V_c=\frac{21\times2.66\,k\Omega}{(14000+2.66)\,k\Omega}=0.39V\to Q'=0.0186Q$$

Answer (score 1):

With R2 in the circuit, you can solve for the *steady state* voltage across the capacitor very simply since, in steady state, the current through the capacitor is zero (like an open circuit).

Thus, by voltage division, the voltage across the capacitor is:

$V_C = V \dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}$

Since $Q = CV_C$, reducing the charge by 16% requires only reducing the capacitor voltage by 16%:

$V_C = 0.84 V$

Thus, you must solve the following equation:

$\dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} = 0.84$

It is clear that the given answer for R2 cannot be correct.